# Eclipse doesn't run my project

Tags: eclipse, project, android

In Eclipse I tried to run my project with Ctrl + F11 (Button Run in menu I also checked). Then coming Android Device Chooser, I choose my phone and wait my app running. But nothing happens. I checked with another project, and it works good, application was running in my phone. Why does it happen?

Thanks.

Comment: We need more information to be able to help; what do the console and logcat messages say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse look at the out put from Console and LogCat.

Comment: In console I see this: Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
I found decision. Thank you!